# How to infer the constrained infimum of this quadratic function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

Given that $z \leq 0$, I want to find

$$
\inf_{t \geq z-1} \frac{1}{2} t^2 + 1 - z + t
$$

in terms of $z$.

I can make a smart guess and realise that for a candidate $t'= -1$ we'd get

$$
 \frac{1}{2} t'^2 + 1 - z + t' = \frac{1}{2} - z
$$

However, it is not clear to me how to verify that $t'$ is indeed the minimiser. Since the infimum is constrained, you cannot simply take the derivative and set it to zero to find the minimum.

Would appreciate if someone hinted me at the thought process about how to deal with such problems. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use further properties (in this case monotonicity) of the function you want to minimize.

First not that the '$1-z$'-part does not depend on $t$ so you are only trying to minimize $\frac{1}{2}t^2+t$ over the set $\{t\geq z-1\}$.

As you guessed correctly without the constraint $t\geq z-1$ this would be minimized for $t=-1$.

So especially if $-1\in \{t\geq z-1\}$ the minimum is given by $\frac{1}{2}-z$.

For $t>-1$ the funtion $\frac{1}{2}t^2+t$ is (strictly) monotonically increasing.

So it will be minimized by the smallest $t$ that is still in $\{t\geq z-1\}$, i.e. $t=z-1$.